# How to implement subheaders/sections inside a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to implement [subheaders](https://material.io/guidelines/components/subheaders.html#) inside my `RecyclerView`. As the adapter for my `RecyclerView`, I am using the [`PagedListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter.html) from the brand new [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) with the combination of [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html).

The data coming from the database contains dates. I want to separate/group the items by day and show the date inside the subheader.

What would be the best way to implement [subheaders](https://material.io/guidelines/components/subheaders.html#) with this combination? AFAIK it is impossible to implement this the 'standard' ViewType way, because that would replace the first data list item with the header. At this moment I am trying to accomplish it with `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`, but I am not able to make it work.

**Can anyone point me in the right direction?**

So far my `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`:

```
public class RecyclerViewHeaderItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private RecyclerViewHeaderReceiver receiver;

public RecyclerViewHeaderItemDecoration setReceiver(RecyclerViewHeaderReceiver receiver) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    return this;

}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        if (receiver != null) {
            View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            int previousPosition = position - 1;
            if (position == 0 || (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && receiver.isNewSection(previousPosition, position))) {
                ViewHolder headerView = receiver.getSectionHeaderViewHolder(position);
                parent.getAdapter().bindViewHolder(headerView, position); // I was not able to 'insert' a new viewHolder
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface RecyclerViewHeaderReceiver {
    boolean isNewSection(int prevPosition, int position);
    ViewHolder getSectionHeaderViewHolder(int position);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

so I was solving the same problem as you recently and I managed to accomplish it with this library

https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor

It uses the ItemDecoration approach you have been trying.